# How to retrieve just one value from a list with enumerations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enums

We have a script which, after calling, return this variable:

```py
list = [Enum string="1X", Enum string="2X"]
```

Now, the issue is, that when I am trying to extract 1X and 2X as strings from this list with RegEx (re module), it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Even when I try to manually assign any other variable with value like [Enum string="1X", Enum string="2X"], it would give me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The question is - How do I extract the strings that are in the `Enum string="SOMETHING HERE"` in Python?

Comment: `list = [Enum string="1X", Enum string="2X"]` is not a valid python code. Update the question with valid python code.

Comment: What's the code that uses regex? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @balderman exactly, but that is what our API returns to us. Is it possible to fix it when it is returned in Python?

Comment: add the EXACT string that you get from the API and the sub strings you want to extract from it.

Comment: Do you mean that you got it as string for each element? Like "enum = x1"? Or legal enum? Moreover dont call your variable after python type, `list` is not a good name

Comment: @balderman it returns exacly as mentioned in the post. I need the text between “” after the text Enum string=

Comment: @YossiLevi not sure what legal enum is?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

`Enum string="1X"` is not python code.
But let's say we want to extract the "1X" from it. We can use a regex!

Let's assume the whole output of the script is a string :

```
code_string = '[Enum string="1X", Enum string="2X"]'
pattern = '=.*?[\d\w]+'

matchs = re.findall(pattern, code_string)
print([match[2:] for match in matchs])
# Returns > ['1X', '2X']
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn’t make it clear but RegEx is not the issue. The issue is - how do I convert that non-Pythonic returned text into a string so that I can use RegEx over it?

Answer (score 0):

If you copy pasted this line into your code, then:

```
list = [Enum string="1X", Enum string="2X"]
```

Could be changed to

```
from enum import Enum
class YourEnumName(Enum):
    x1 = "1X"
    x2 = "2X"
```

I am sorry if this did not answer your question, it is difficult to understand what you want. The question isn't clear as we are not sure of what the input data is. Is it A string? A copy/pasted non-python line of code? i'm sure a little bit more context would help people solve your issue. ;)